# solar pv micro-inverter strings

Tags: inverter, solar-energy

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_micro-inverter); a solar micro-inverter is a plug-and-play device used in photovoltaics, that converts direct current (DC) generated by a single solar module to alternating current (AC).

I can understand the benefits of having micro-inverters on every panel increases efficiency for a number of reasons; owing to moving AC is more efficient than DC and their MPPT capabilities.

The question that I wanted to ask is, how do you create micro-inverter strings?

Let's say you have 10 panels rated at 300 watts, each tracking their maximum power point. Now each micro-inverter outputs 110v AC.

That's 10 panels each outputting 110v AC. How do you combine those AC output?

Comment: SMVs are DESIGNED to connect to a "stiff" 110 VAC (or 230VAC) bus. They synchronise in frequency and voltage and adjust phase angle to control energy transfer. In the absence of system wide control they maximise energy transfer based on available energy input and their maximum capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solar Micro Inverters are DESIGNED to connect to a "stiff" 110 VAC (or 230VAC) bus.

They synchronise in frequency and voltage and adjust phase angle to control energy transfer. In the absence of system wide control they maximise energy transfer based on available energy input and their maximum capacity.

Many such devices can be controlled by a centralised system but this is not essential to their operation.

They are largely, as you note, "plug and play".
Connect PV input,
Connect mains output to mains AC bus.
Done.